# How regex lookaround works when used alone

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pattern a = Pattern.compile("(?=\\.)|(?<=\\.)");
        Matcher b = a.matcher(".");
        while (b.find()) System.out.print("+");
    }
}
```

I've been reading the lookaround section on Regular-Expressions.info and trying to figure out how it works, and I'm stuck with this thing. when I run the code above the result is ++, which I don't understand, because since "." is the only token to match the pattern against, and apparently there's nothing behind or ahead of the "." so how can it match twice?

Comment: @hwnd well I understand lookarounds doesn't consume any token, but what i don't understand is, there is no token behind or ahead of the ".", and since i only have the lookbehind and lookahead and not \\. in the pattern i compiled, i think it should not match anything but somehow it matches twice.

Comment: `^^^` You're getting two matches because of the [zero-width](https://regex101.com/r/rI5bH1/2) positions.

Comment: @hwnd sorry for keep bothering you...doesn't zero-width mean it is an assertion(that there should be a period either ahead or behind the current position) which doesn't consume any token?(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275375/zero-width-token) i don't get what you mean by zero-width positions... do you mean something like the blank before and after the "." ?

Comment: @hwnd oops...my reputation is to low to talk in the chat...thanks for the help! i'll try to figure out what you've said in that post and maybe come back when i have higher reputation....

Comment: The regex: `(?=\.)|(?<=\.)` says, in English: _"Match a position in the string that is either immediately before or after a period"_ In other words, a zero width assertion matches a _position_ or _location_ in a string. If there is one period in a string, there will be two positions that match - one before and one after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the regex engine advances through the input, it considers both characters *and* positions *before and after* characters as distinct positions within the input.

Your input has 3 positions:

1. Just before the first character
2. The first character
3. Just after the first character

Position 1 matches `(?=\\.)`.
Position 3 matches `(?<=\\.)`.